# Dockerfile rsyslog

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rsyslog

I have implemented a dockerfile to have a postfix that logs using rsyslog, but it raises an error while running.

Output Error:

```
tail: cannot open '/var/log/mail.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-modules postfix rsyslog && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY main.cf /etc/postfix/
COPY ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

EXPOSE 25

CMD service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:

```
RUN touch /dev/xconsole && chgrp syslog /dev/xconsole && chmod 664 /dev/xconsole
RUN service rsyslog restart
```

And update `CMD` to start *rsyslog* at first:

```
CMD service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Because `RUN` executes command during the image build whereas `CMD` executes command in the running container and you need to run rsyslogd in a running container.

Result *Dockerfile* can look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-modules postfix rsyslog; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "[smtp.gmail.com]:587 email@gmail.com:password" > /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd; \
    postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd; \
    sed -i '/relayhost*/c\relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587' /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    sed -i '/smtp_sasl_auth_enable*/c\smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes' /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    sed -i '/smtp_sasl_security_options*/c\smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous' /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    sed -i '/smtp_sasl_password_maps*/c\smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd' /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    sed -i '/smtp_tls_security_level*/c\smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt' /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    sed -i '/smtp_tls_CAfile*/c\smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' /etc/postfix/main.cf

EXPOSE 587

CMD service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Build it: `docker build -t postfix -f Dockerfile.postfix .`

And when you run it: `docker run -it --rm --name postfix postfix`

... then you have mail log in console:

```
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                                                                                                   postfix: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
postfix: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
postfix: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
                                                                                                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix[111]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix[111]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix[111]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix/master[156]: daemon started -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix/pickup[159]: error: open file /etc/mailname: No such file or directory
Sep 26 20:11:01 6009a2e3d206 postfix/qmgr[160]: error: open file /etc/mailname: No such file or directory
```

You can also check the mail log using exec command: `docker exec postfix cat /var/log/mail.log`. This can be helpful when running container as a daemon (`-d` flag).

---

Regarding the `rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe` error - you can ignore it.

But if you don't want to ignore it you can update your `CMD` and have it like this:

```
CMD touch /dev/xconsole && chgrp syslog /dev/xconsole && chmod 664 /dev/xconsole && service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Comment: everything works fine except when i add COPY / ADD before EXPOSE command like this (COPY main.cf /etc/postfix/), it results to
`tail: cannot open '/var/log/mail.log' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: I tried that and it _works_. It works also with incorrect _main.cf_ file and shows `* Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd [ OK ]
 * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix 
postmulti: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 1: missing '=' after attribute name: "test"` Postfix shows error because of incorrect config file nevertheless the rsyslog is running and _/var/log/mail.log_ file was created and container runs without exit. From my point of view you have problem somewhere else. Did you try it with exactly the same _Dockerfile_ as is in the answer?

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with this rsyslog thing, there must be a solution to it, coz it just randomly worked fine and sometimes it doesn't, I really couldn't tell why. But here is my final and simple Dockerfile but still the problem is there. Also, whenever I tried to update it, it just raises an error.